# Adding text to Sharepoint 2010 surveys

Tags: 2010, survey-list

I've created a survey in Sharepoint 2010 and I need to be able to add large blocks of text and diagrams above specific questions but there doesn't seem to be a way to do this.

I've tried adding the text to a question itself, which is ok, however it doesn't allow me to format it or add images, plus any 'lookup' type question (which is often the type of question that I need to add text above) only allows a fixed number of characters.

Is this possible using the Sharepoint survey, or do I perhaps need to consider other alternatives, such as InfoPath forms?

Thanks in advance,

QJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint designer.  an example from a MOSS survey but 2010 will be similar.

http://stevenderveaux.wordpress.com/2009/08/07/customizing-a-sharepoint-survey-newform-aspx-page/

Answer (score 0):

In MOSS 2007 we took another route.  It involves adding a Content Editor Web Part to the user response page and using JQuery and/or Javascript to hide the response of the survey.

Here's a link to a site that helped me figure out how to add the Content Editor Web Part to the user response page:  http://www.sharepointkings.com/2008/05/how-to-edit-list-forms-like-newformaspx.html

You basically append **&ToolPaneView=2** to the url on the page that loads after you click "Respond to Survey".

I had to host the JQuery file in a local document library, giving everyone access to it - this avoids the annoying pop-up message that occurs when loading the JQuery file from a non *https* site.  This may not be necessary in 2010.

Any section where we wanted only text, but no user response, we made a choice question with the only response being a period (.).  Once we had the Content Editor Web Part available, we added the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://yoursite.com/location/of/jquery/file/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
      $('[title="."]').hide();
</script>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me (using Sharepoint 2010), because clicking on "Respond to Survey" opens a pop-up, without an address bar. Going to the survey settings shows the survey address, but adding "&toolpaneview=2" to the provided address results in a could not load error. Thanks, Dave Castor