# How to duplicate a question in a survey?

Tags: 2007, jquery, survey-list, unique

We have a survey that has 10 main questions.  All of these questions are unique.  After each question, we want to show last year's average answer to the same survey question.  We're able to insert basic text using the method I illustrate as an answer to this question:  [Adding text to Sharepoint 2010 surveys](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16156/adding-text-to-sharepoint-2010-surveys)

The only problem is that we want to use the same text in the statement that shows last year's average answer.  This poses a problem when the averages, and thus the questions, are identical.  We receive this pop-up message:

[image: The question has already been added to the survey. Please enter a unique question name.]

I know we can add something unique to the question to make it different, like 1a) or something similar, but this is confusing because it's not actually a question.  Does anyone have any ideas how to get around this unique question text requirement?

Comment: I tried using different symbols like a series of periods (adding one for each question) but it still looks unprofessional. Has anyone come up with another workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each question is essentially a column, you could ask the question in a different format. You have to tell yourself, if the questions aren't really identical in what it's asking, let's change the question. If the data being last year is what is unique, include that in the question.

Otherwise you need to find a way to trick SharePoint to use the same format but maybe something like two spaces between two words...

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by adding spaces at the end of the question. SharePoint accepted it and the user couldn't tell the difference.

Comment: This works only if I have a multi-line question (because I can put extra spaces at the end of the first line).  If I try to add extra spaces at the very end of the last line, SharePoint trims them off and the questions are once again identical.